# Как браузер понимает какой тип шрифтов использовать(ttf,eot,woff)?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Привет!Хотелось бы задать вопрос знающим людям как браузер понимает какой ему использовать тип шрифта?И как мне сделать так чтобы в хроме грузился тип woff,а в опере woff?

Answer (score 3):

Есть замечательный ресурс https://caniuse.com (смотрим поддержку).Сейчас достаточно:

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'Web font'; 
  src: url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Только если нужна поддержка старых Android, иначе закомментировать */ 
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

На developers.google приводится пример как браузер определяет, что для отображении сайта нужен какой-либо шрифт, он читает предоставленных список ресурсов в указанном порядке и старается скачать нужный шрифт.
1)Браузер читает разметку страницы и определяет, какие варианты шрифтов нужны для отрисовки текста.
2)Браузер проверяет, не установлены ли нужные шрифты на устройстве.
3)Если файла нет на устройстве, браузер читает список внешних расположений:
4)Если формат указан, перед скачивание браузер проверяется, поддерживается ли он. В случае отрицательного ответа программа переходит к следующему варианту.
5)Если указание на формат отсутствует, браузер скачивает ресурс.